# Caching usercontrol in Repeater using VaryByControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, user-controls

I'm trying to cache multiple `userControls` that are displayed in a `Repeater` i.e. one `usercontrol` is within each `ItemTemplate` of the `Repeater`.

The `userControl` has a custom property passed into it, in this case (in an ecommerce site) it is the Product object.

I had initially thought about using the `VaryByCustom` property, but in the overriden `GetVaryByCustomString` method in the Global class I wont have access to the Product's ID, so I thought that wouldn't work.

I then looked at `VaryByControl` as an option. Within the usercontrol that I want cached I added a `HiddenField` and then programatically set the ID of the `HiddenField` in `Load` method (I tried Init and `CreateChildControls` too), like so:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="None" VaryByControl="ProductIdHiddenField" %>
```

And then in the code-behind:

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.ProductIdHiddenField.ID = string.Concat(ProductIdHiddenField, "_", Product.ProductId, "_", Product.GetCategories().FirstOrDefault().CategoryId);
    }
```

However, this doesnt seem to happen early enough and therefore despite which page I visit on the site, the Product shown in 1st position within the `Repeater` is always the same i.e. it should be different between Category page to Category page as they contain different products.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

The basic result that I am trying to acheive is that the usercontrol is cached by the `Product` property which is passed into the `UserControl`.

Many thanks in advance
dotdev